# Gem5 giving no spare thread error?

Tags: memory, gem5

I tried to run gem5 in SE mode and it is giving an error:

```
fatal: Clone: no spare thread context in system
```

Can someone please point it out where the problem in gem5 is?

Comment: Are you trying to run a multithreaded program? If so this link from Gem5's mailing list might be useful: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg14244.html

Comment: How did you create / obtain the executable? What is the full gem5 command line? What is the gem5 git revision?

Comment: When executing this:  build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py -c tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/hello  its working fine .When i am trying to run my own program:  build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py -c tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/rowham1iter its giving this error